# How to compare Eigen:Arrays rowwise, but unordered?

Tags: c++, eigen, googletest

I am writing a unit test for a function that computes a Eigen array of 4 row vectors of size 2. I would like to check whether it is approximately equal to the expected result, but the rows do not necessarily have to appear in the same order. So for each row in the actual output, I want to see whether it matches *some* row in the expected output.

So this is my test now

```
Eigen::Array<float, 4, 2> expectedResult {{-14.1421356F, -14.1421356F},
                                          {-28.2842712F, 28.2841712F},
                                          {14.1421356F, 14.1421356F},
                                          {28.2842712F, -28.284172F}};

Eigen::Array<float, 4, 2> result = myFunction();
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 4; rowIndex++)
{
        // Check whether each row of result matches some other row of expectedResult,
        // not necessarily in order.
        // @todo find less clumsy way
        bool foundMatch = false;
        for (int comparisonRowIndex = 0; comparisonRowIndex < 4; comparisonRowIndex++)
        {
            if (result.row(rowIndex).isApprox(expectedResult.row(comparisonRowIndex), TOLERANCE))
            {
                foundMatch = true;
            }
        }
        EXPECT_TRUE(foundMatch);
}
```

This does not feel satisfactory and I'm thinking I should surely be able to use Eigen's `any()` construct in some way, but I still haven't found out why. This is my best shot, which however doesn't compile

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < 4; rowIndex++)
{
    EXPECT_TRUE(expectedResult.rowwise().isApprox(result.row(rowIndex), TOLERANCE).any());  // WRONG
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that your code does not compile is because the return value of `expectedResult.rowwise` is not an array and thus does not have the member `isApprox`. It rather is a [`VectorwiseOp`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1VectorwiseOp.html), see [the documentation of `rowwise`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#aa1cabd3404528fe8cec4bab43d74bffc) *(Next time, please include your compiler error in your question)*.

I am not an expert on Eigen, but your problem seems to be so specific that I have a hunch that there is no dedicated functionality in Eigen to solve your problem.

You don't specify why you think your approach is "clumsy". I think your approach in general is okay, you need to check every row in the source array against every row in the target array, there is no way around it. The situation would be different if you could provide a partial ordering comparator function for the rows: Then you could sort the rows manually or potentially make use of `std::set`.

You can however improve on the efficiency by reducing the number of comparisons:

1. If for one row in the source array you cannot find a matching row in the target array, you can stop your function and return false. Apparently the two arrays do not have approximately matching rows
2. If for one row in the source array you find a matching row in the target array, you can stop searching for matches to this row in the source array: You already have found a match.
3. If for one row in the source array you find a matching row in the target array, you do not have to consider this target row in the subsequent iterations over the source array rows.

```cpp
template <typename T, int nrows, int ncols>
auto compare_by_rows_unordered(
    Eigen::Array<T, nrows, ncols> const& source,
    Eigen::Array<T, nrows, ncols> const& target,
    T tolerance
) -> bool
{
    bool rows_match_approx = true;

    // keep a set of target rows to check against. At the beginning this set contains all rows
    std::set<int> target_rows;                   
    for (int i = 0; i < nrows; ++i) {
        target_rows.insert(target_rows.end(), i);
    }

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < nrows; rowIndex++)
    {
            bool foundMatch = false;
            for (int comparisonRowIndex : target_rows)
            {
                std::cout << "i = " << rowIndex << ", j = " << comparisonRowIndex << "\n";
                if (source.row(rowIndex).isApprox(target.row(comparisonRowIndex), tolerance))
                {
                    std::cout << "MATCH!\n";
                    target_rows.erase(comparisonRowIndex);      // 3. target row has been found and does not need to be considered in future comparisons
                    foundMatch = true;
                    break;                                      // 2. no need to check if the source row matches more than one target row
                }
            }
            if (!foundMatch) {
                rows_match_approx = false;
                break;                                          // 1. source row matches no row in target. The arrays don't have the same rows! We can exit now
            }
    }

    return rows_match_approx;
}
```

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/6oTacj87j

---

### Addendum

As @chtz pointed out in his comment, there may be cases where this check fails. The reason for this is that "approximate equality" is not an equivalence relation. More specifically, it is not transitive, i.e. `x.isApprox(y,tol)` and `y.isApprox(z,tol)` does not imply `x.isApprox(z,tol)`.

As an example, let's consider a simplified version of your problem, where we want to compare arrays with two rows each of length 1, i.e. two two-element vectors s and t.

| s | t |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 0.91 | 1.09 |

Here, it holds `s[0].isApprox(t[0], 0.1)`, `s[0].isApprox(t[1], 0.1)`, `s[1].isApprox(t[0], 0.1)` but not `s[1].isApprox(t[1], 0.1)`. Rules 2 and 3 would match `s[0]` with `t[0]` and since `t[0]` will be removed from the set of candidate rows, `s[1]` has nothing to match against, and the function would return `false`, which is likely unexpected.

So is it safer to not exclude any comparisons?

No, not really. Let's forgoe rules 1, 2 and 3 and rigorously compare each source row with each target row of the following inputs:

| s | t |
| --- | --- |
| 1.0 | 1.0 |
| 0.91 | 42.0 |

Then, given a tolerance of 0.1, your proposed algorithm would match both `s[0]` and `s[1]` to `t[0]` and since every source row has a match in the target array your algorithm would return `true`, which is probably also not what you would expect.

Long story short, floating point comparisons have intricate pitfalls and having a comparison function that respects all edge cases is not a trivial task, if possible at all.

Comment: This might fail, if `source.row(0)` is approximately equal to `target.row` 0 and 1, but `source.row(1)` only approximately equal to `target.row(0)`. Not sure if this happens in OP's usecases or what behavior they would like (in OP's implementation, it would not matter if a target row is not matched by a source row, if another target row is matched by two source rows -- which is also likely not intended behavior).

Comment: Ah good point. It would work, if the relation "approximate equality" were transitive like equality is, but this isn't true in general. So skipping comparisons might miss some edge cases depending on the choice of the tolerance.

Comment: I added a remark to my answer. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Thanks, I'm thinking that efficiency is not important in unit tests so that's not a reason for increasing the complexity. OTOH, your suggestion will make the test less forgiving so we don't get false positives. If I know my ground truth does not have any approximately equal values, then chtz's objection doesn't apply.